# SFML how to draw a Sprite(used as a player) on a Sprite(used as map)

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm not familiar with the SFML environment yet, we started learning it this year at school
I'm struggling to draw a sprite on another sprite using this method
I guess this s.~Drawable(); is used to draw on another windows but i couldn't find any example to implement it anyone could redirect me to a good documentation that is easy to understands for begginers.
Thanks.

PS: I found other methods but I need to load image everytimes to change the player's sprite image and I guess this would slow down the game fps depending on the user drive

```
int sizeX = 1920, sizeY = 1080;
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(sizeX, sizeY), "Test");
window.setFramerateLimit(60); // max FPS a 60

sf::Vector2f player1(10, 10);
sf::Vector2f player2(590, 10);
sf::Sprite paddle1;
sf::Sprite paddle2;
sf::Texture t;
t.loadFromFile("Background.png");
sf::Sprite s(t);
//s.~Drawable(); 





// chargement du fichier .jpg dans un objet image de type Texture
sf::Texture imageBack1;
sf::Texture imageBack2;
sf::Texture imageForward1;
sf::Texture imageForward2;
sf::Texture imageLeft;
sf::Texture imageRight;
// PLayer2
sf::Texture imageBack1b;
sf::Texture imageBack2b;
sf::Texture imageForward1b;
sf::Texture imageForward2b;
sf::Texture imageLeftb;
sf::Texture imageRightb;


if (!imageBack1.loadFromFile("Back1.png"))
    printf("PB de chargement de l'image !\n");
if (!imageBack2.loadFromFile("Back2.png"))
    printf("PB de chargement de l'image !\n");
if (!imageForward1.loadFromFile("Forward1.png"))
    printf("PB de chargement de l'image !\n");
if (!imageForward2.loadFromFile("Forward2.png"))
    printf("PB de chargement de l'image !\n");
if (!imageLeft.loadFromFile("Left.png"))
    printf("PB de chargement de l'image !\n");
if (!imageRight.loadFromFile("Right.png"))
    printf("PB de chargement de l'image !\n");

//Player2 I guess this can be removed
if (!imageBack1b.loadFromFile("Back1b.png"))
    printf("PB de chargement de l'image !\n");
if (!imageBack2b.loadFromFile("Back2b.png"))
    printf("PB de chargement de l'image !\n");
if (!imageForward1b.loadFromFile("Forward1b.png"))
    printf("PB de chargement de l'image !\n");
if (!imageForward2b.loadFromFile("Forward2b.png"))
    printf("PB de chargement de l'image !\n");
if (!imageLeftb.loadFromFile("Leftb.png"))
    printf("PB de chargement de l'image !\n");
if (!imageRightb.loadFromFile("Rightb.png"))
    printf("PB de chargement de l'image !\n");


/* L’image doit être associée à un objet de type Sprite (équivalent à un rectangle) pour être dessinée. Ici , le sprite s’appelle bonhomme. Après, on ne travaille plus que sur le sprite… image ne sert plus à rien*/
paddle1.setTexture(imageBack1);
paddle2.setTexture(imageBack1);

// Start the game loop
while (window.isOpen())
{

    // Poll for events
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        // Close window : exit
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window.close();

        // Escape pressed : exit
        if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Escape)
            window.close();
    }

    
    window.clear();

    // Draw the sprites
    window.draw(paddle1);
    window.draw(paddle2);
    window.draw(s);
    window.display();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could draw to a sf::RenderTexture: https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1RenderTexture.php

And have this render texture be the texture of the Sprite.

Comment: Thanks you i just find out that there is several "layouts" of "textures" I thought i would have to make a new window and draw on it this should help a lot.